# Flutter Web: Divider color not showing when scrolling page

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In my flutter project, the `Divider` widget color is not showing when scrolling.
The issue exists only in flutter web project.

Comment: can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last two years I have been using this divider code below. It working well for all platforms. To fix your issue, provide your code.

```
Widget commonDividerWidget(Color color) {
  return Divider(
    thickness: 1.0,
    color: color,
  );
}
```

Comment: Providing the `thickness` attribute solved the issue in web